# PHP Upload Progressbar with Curl

Tags: php, ajax, curl, progress-bar

I created a regular upload function with CURL in PHP that uploads a file to a ftp server with authentication.
My goal is to call this function over AJAX.
Is it possible that this function returns a percentage of how much of the file it already uploaded to the server so that a progress bar could be built.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$localfile = './test.jpg';
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'sftp://0.0.0.0/upload/test.jpg');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php "CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION".

Comment: Implement the progressbar in javascript. Doing it in PHP will shorten your lifespan.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. It functioned perfectly with curlopt_progressfunction